# How remove "SMS" permission to share?

Tags: android, permissions, sms

Google has introduced a policy to restrict SMS permission: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303

My app use shared preferences, but i don't need SMS in my app. I need remove that for solve.

It says: Apps that fail to meet policy requirements or submit a Permissions Declaration Form by January 9, 2019 may be removed from Google Play.

My code:

```
private void shareScreenshot(File file) {
    Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(JogoImparImparActivity.this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",file);
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getString(R.string.sharing_text)+" https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=loremlorem");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.share_title)));
}
```

Comment: Is sms permission available in ur AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: No, the intent automatically selects system apps to share.

Answer (score 1):

When you are sharing the screenshot from ur application, using `Intent.createChooser()`, you are giving the android device/sdk, to pick the applications which can be used to share the picture, eg: whatsapp, sms, ... the app is selected based on the intent type (i.e. `image/*` , ) and action ( `Intent.ACTION_SEND` ) , this doesn't violate the policy to restrict the sms permission which you are referring in your question.

Check the article for more details on how the android system picks the apps based on the intent type, intent action, https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send

Comment: I understand, but Google sent me by email stating that my app will be removed should I not remove the use of SMS. This is the only part of my app that uses some SMS.

Comment: "If your app does not require access to Call Log or SMS permissions, you must remove these permissions from your app's manifest. " this is the statement i have copied from the reference link that you have posted, As long as you are sticking to it , i don't see any issue